# Is onStop() called on the main thread

Tags: android

Is Activity.onStop() called on the main thread?
Also not sure about onPause() and onDestroy(). Are those all called on the main thread>?

Comment: Yes. All of an `Activity`'s lifecycle methods are called on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also consider onStart() between onCreate and onResume; and onStop() between onPause and onDestroy on the same line.

[image]